# How do I get the RECT of title bar's window controls (maximize, minimize, close buttons) ? I tried to make a custom color title bar

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, controls

I am trying to intercept the WM_NCPAINT message by first calling ::DefWindowProc, then paint over it. However, when I paint the window controls of the title bar or non-client area, I need to have its RECT structure. Therefore, how do I access the REcT structure?

Comment: which version of windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update region is passed in message's `wParam`. The non client area of the window isn't rectangular so you don't get a single `RECT`.

I presume you are aware that `WM_
NCPAINT` is not compatible with Vista DWM glass.

Comment: I mean the window controls such as maximize/minimize button. How do I get their regions? I want to override it with a custom bitmap

Comment: In that case I suggest that you ask the question that you want to be answered. Do you know that your current method doesn't work with glass? Have downloaded from the web one of the many sample projects the customise non client area?

Comment: ça you provide more details about painting & Vista & Glass?

Comment: @mox There are lots of examples on the web.  For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688195%28VS.85%29.aspx and the key is  DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea